# bootstrap3.7 modal adapt width to content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a modal that would adapt to the with of the content that I'm giving it to.

The modal that I'm using is pretty simple. Nothing fancy.

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

            <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div  class="modal-body">
            <div id="modalBody">

                @*<select id="hiddenMenu" class="form-control"></select>*@

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="editRuleModalFooter" class="modal-footer">

            <button id="modalSaveButton" data-toggle="modal" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>

            <button id="modalCancelButton" data-toggle="modal" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to give them class="col-xs-12" and that Didn't help. But adding a style of width 1000px made it bigger but the modal would expand to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Use large modals like this:

```html
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <p>Your content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```